# How can I undo editing an indexed file in Git?

Tags: git, git-diff, vimdiff

This looks strange but I don't understand what happened.

I was checking the `gitdiff` using vimdiff (using `vim-fugitive`). Then, while being in the indexed buffer, I presed `dp` which should put the changes in the indexed version into the working version. I pressed something afterwards, by mistake, that I can't recognize then the indexed buffer was deleted and it became empty. I closed that window. Now when I run `gitdiff` again, the whole file in working copy is added as it is compared with an empty file.

I don't know what happend and how can I fix it.

Comment: Did you try reverting the file?

Comment: I have no experience in git. Revert means bring the file to its state in the last commit, right? I don't want to lose my changes.

Comment: OK, in that case, if your diff is still valid, just add the lines that you want to be committed. What you had prepared for the commit is gone, you can't go back.

Comment: There are many changes that are hard to be all remembered so I think you mean I just add the file, right? I don't understand how could this happen anyway. Shouldn't the indexed file be a read-only file?

Comment: Well, you can always check you have in the staging area and what you have ont he repository that is already committed.

Answer (score 0):

Try a `git log` in order to see your commit history. Analyse your last commit and check if all it is fine